# How to view details of "Kernel Stack" memory

Tags: memory, windows-11

I'm running Windows 11, 22H2. Something strange started recently (I believe after I updated to 22H2). I would notice that sometimes, my computer would become VERY unresponsive. I opened task manager to find 99% of my 32 GB of memory used, though there were no processes that seemed to be using a larger than normal amount of memory, and the memory displayed in the column didn't seem to add up to close to my machine's 32 GB. I also have 90GB of hard drive free. Restarting my machhine always seems to address the problem.

The problem came back, and to investigate further, I used RamMap: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap

[image: Image of RamMap showing possible memory leak]

What I found was interesting: while in this bad state, RamMap showed that the amount of "Kernel Stack" memory was over 12 gb. This seemed like it could be the culprit. After restarting, it was around 50,000kb. I suspect there may be a memory leak. I'm wondering if it's possible for me to explore a bit deeper what is inside kernel stack memory, or if there's any way to observe when a process writes to that memory. As well, any background info on what this memory is used for would be helfpul.

Thanks...

Comment: "Kernel Stack" is more often associated with device drivers, which in this case would mean a problem with one of your devices. In any case, when it happens try to run the script in [this page](https://docs.syntevo.com/SmartGit/HowTos/Your-system-ran-out-of-virtual-memory.html).

Comment: The very nature of your question tells me probably not, you are probably not going to be successful at this.  This isn't as simple as looking at a call stack.  To do single machine kernel debugging will require you to make changes to your BCD entry to allow it, extensive knowledge of WinDbg and debugging in general, and debug symbols.  You "might" be able to see what is going on "from the outside" using something like procmon and watching the activity though.